# Resizing a fullscreen browser

Tags: firefox

On websites such as Google Photos, or Flickr, I want to launch slideshows, but also be able to change the size of the browser window. For instance, I want to be able to put a slideshow only on one half of the screen, and another slideshow on the other half.

However, when a Slideshow is launched on those sites, it makes the browser go into fullscreen mode. Thus, I can't resize the windows, nor can I put them on one half of the screen.

I've looked on the web but the solutions often imply writing some code or using a very deprecated extension. I haven't found any extension or trick that would allow me to be able to change the size of my browser window while it displays the fullscreen slideshow.

Would you have any idea on how to resize a browser that is already in fullscreen mode?

I'm using Firefox.